# Can't get Xdebug work more than 5 minutes. Timeout happens

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I am getting the below error while i a trying to debug a php application which is based on yii framework. The exception comes in Netbeans browser is a 'Socket exception occurred'. This happens every time i try after 2 - 5 minutes.

**EDITED:**

I am using IIS server.

[image]

how can i resolve this ?

I found the following configuration under iis and increased it to 30 minutes but still the issue remains.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to IIS -> FastCGI Setiings

Then increase the idle time out

Attached a screen.

[image]